# Process JSON data and JSON object arrays using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON feed I'm working with that contains one instance of `attributes` and many objects inside `posts`.

I have a javascript algorithm that I'm processing the JSON data and I am getting the `attributes` values fine (they act as settings) but I can't process the `posts` properly.

**JSON Response**

```
[
  {
  "attributes":{
     "dfp_pos":"3",
     "dfp_shortcode":"[dfp_ads id=1383]",
     "wildcard_pos":"5",
     "wildcard_shortcode":"[widget id=\"wp_widget-46\"]",
     "twitter_id":"@ScreenName",
     "twitter_pos":"8",
     "facebook_id":"screenName",
     "facebook_pos":"10"
  },
  "posts":[
     {
        "id":3945,
        "pub_date":"2016-05-30 00:00:00",
        "title":"Post title 1",
        "excerpt":""
     },
     {
        "id":3574,
        "pub_date":"2016-05-12 00:00:00",
        "title":"Post Title 2",
        "excerpt":""
     },
     {
        "id":3048,
        "pub_date":"2016-05-07 00:00:00",
        "title":"Post Title 3",
        "excerpt":""
     }
   ]
]
```

**Javascript**

```
var dfp_pos = feeds[0].attributes.dfp_pos;
var dfp_shortcode = feeds[0].attributes.dfp_shortcode;
var wildcard_pos = feeds[0].attributes.wildcard_pos;
var wildcard_shortcode = feeds[0].attributes.wildcard_shortcode;
var twitter_id = feeds[0].attributes.twitter_id;
var twitter_pos = feeds[0].attributes.twitter_pos;
var facebook_id = feeds[0].attributes.facebook_id;
var facebook_pos = feeds[0].attributes.facebook_pos;

jQuery.each(feeds.posts, function(i, post) {
    var id = post.id;
    var pub_date = post.pub_date;
    var title = post.title;
    var excerpt = post.excerpt;

    console.log(id);
    console.log(pub_date);
    console.log(title);
    console.log(excerpt);
});
```

The `each` loop doesn't seem to pull the through the JSON data?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot one layer:

```
data = [
       ^  {
       |  ^  "attributes":{
       |  |  "posts":[
       |  |   ^
       1  2   3
```

giving you:

```
data[0].posts
 ^   ^    ^
 1   2    3
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through feeds[0]

```
var dfp_pos = feeds[0].attributes.dfp_pos;
var dfp_shortcode = feeds[0].attributes.dfp_shortcode;
var wildcard_pos = feeds[0].attributes.wildcard_pos;
var wildcard_shortcode = feeds[0].attributes.wildcard_shortcode;
var twitter_id = feeds[0].attributes.twitter_id;
var twitter_pos = feeds[0].attributes.twitter_pos;
var facebook_id = feeds[0].attributes.facebook_id;
var facebook_pos = feeds[0].attributes.facebook_pos;

jQuery.each(feeds[0].posts, function(i, post) {
    var id = post.id;
    var pub_date = post.pub_date;
    var title = post.title;
    var excerpt = post.excerpt;

    console.log(id);
    console.log(pub_date);
    console.log(title);
    console.log(excerpt);
});
```